# Can I attach a key-value pair to Google Form Response with Google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

For example, I know filling in email address is a bit painful. What I want is, after getting your email by Session.getEffectiveUser(), to attach that email String to the Google Form Response, while all these things done in script.

Is it possible?

Comment: You need to give more details about the context... getting the email address of a user filling a form is only possible if you are running this in a domain account with users belonging to the domain. Is it the case ?

Comment: nope, not the same domain. Just using var x = Session.getEffectiveUser() to get respondent's email.

Then what I want is attach this "x" to the response

Answer (score 0):

Getting the email address of a user filling a form is only possible if you are running this in a domain account or a Google Apps business/education account with users belonging to the same domain.

See [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setCollectEmail%28Boolean%29) for details : *"This feature is available only for forms created by users of Google Apps for Business, Google Apps for Education, or Google Apps for Your Domain. Email addresses for other types of Google accounts cannot be collected. For forms created with other Google accounts, this method throws a scripting exception."*

Comment: In fact, I can get the email already. What I mean is "Whatever var it is, can I attach a new key-value pair to the response and then submit?"